# Operating across HAL versions in STMCubeIDE and running old ANs

Tags: stm32

I'm trying to run an older discovery board using the STM32F334 series of MCU. I'm using the STM32F3348 Discovery Board and attempting to drive its Buck/Boost example from the Cube IDE of the day.

I'm running Cube 1.10.1 and some of the HAL calls appear to be broken. Specificially, the BuckBoost HRTIM example calls the `__GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE()` macro which is defined as `__HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE`. When executing that macro I get an an error from the MCU HAL driver that shipped with CubeIDE:

```
../Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/stm32f3xx_hal_rcc.h:687:40: error: expected expression before 'do'
```

I don't presume this is related to bad code, but rather quite a few version changes in between.

In the interests of assisting the community; "how do I run older discovery boards and examples in STM32CubeIDE when there have been updates to drivers that have resulted in incompatibility?" Should I instead revert to older MCU Packages?